# Computing the automorphism scheme of projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, schemes, projective-geometry

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$I'm trying to understand why $PGL_{n}$ is the automorphism scheme of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

In Conrad's Reductive Group Schemes, the following outline is given as part of an exercise, but I'm having difficulty filling in the details.

> For local $R$ show $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^N_R) = \mathbb{Z}$ by using deformation from the residue field and the theorem on formal functions (after reducing to the case of noetherian $R$). Deduce that the evident action of $PGL_n$ on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ makes it represent the automorphism functor on the category of schemes.

I'd happily accept a reference that works through this or a similar argument more slowly.

#### My thoughts

1. For the reduction to the Noetherian case we use the fact that every $R$ is the colimit of its finitely generated (hence Noetherian) subrings $R_{\alpha}$. So $$\mathbb{P}^N_R = \mathbb{P}^N_{\mathbb{Z}} \times \varprojlim_{\alpha} \Spec R_{\alpha} = \varprojlim_{\alpha} \mathbb{P}^n_{R_{\alpha}}.$$
   If we knew sheaf cohomology commutes with this limit of spaces, then the reduction would follow, but I haven't found a result like that. Is there some completely different way to do the reduction?
2. Now, we would like to lift from the residue field $R/m$ to the completion $\widehat{R} = \varprojlim_i R/m^i$. This lifting argument should probably use that $H^2$ of any invertible sheaf on projective space over a field vanishes to show there is no obstruction to the lifting, but I'm not sure how the argument goes.
3. Grothendieck existence (cf. 4.2 in Illusie's lecture notes [here](https://indico.ictp.it/event/a0255/session/14/contribution/9/material/0/0.pdf)) implies the completion is an equivalence of categories of coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_R$ and $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_{\widehat{R}}$. This implies an isomorphism of Picard groups because the functor commutes with tensor and so whether a coherent sheaf is invertible is preserved across the equivalence. This part seems fine.
4. For the ``deduce" part, the functorial action means we have a morphism of group functors (say, as functors on rings) $PGL_n \to \underline{\operatorname{Aut}}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}$, which is obviously injective. Since both are sheaves, we just need to show sheaf-surjectivity. Given an $R$ and an automorphism $\phi : \mathbb{P}_R^{n-1} \to \mathbb{P}_R^{n-1}$, the automorphism corresponds to a line bundle $L$ on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_R$ and a generating tuple of global sections $s_0, \ldots, s_n$. Somehow we should find a cover adapted to this line bundle which exhibits it locally in the image of the map from $PGL_n$.

Apologies if this is better suited for math.stackexchange; haven't had the best luck there with questions of this flavor.

Comment: This is thoroughly explained in Mumford's *Geometric Invariant Theory*, chapter 0, §5 b).